# User subroutine is missing - Intel Fortran OneAPI with Abaqus

Tags: intel-fortran, abaqus

How do I fix the "***ERROR: USER SUBROUTINE DISP IS MISSING"  during configuration & verification of Intel Fortran (oneAPI) with Abaqus?

Background: Intel have stopped offering parallel studio and have now moved to oneAPI. It seems to be free, but if you were a student or educator, when your old license expires (after a year) you have to move to oneAPI.

Abaqus verification for user subroutines fails with this new platform with the following in the MSG file

```
***ERROR: USER SUBROUTINE DISP IS MISSING
```

As the verification files are provided by Abaqus, it shouldn't fail with this error.

Comment: Please do not enter error messages as pictures. It is paramount they they are actually readable (even for people with disabilities) and searchable. See [ask].

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Good points - sorry I rushed it a bit - hopefully clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the correct components of Visual studio (2019) or later are installed - only the “Desktop development with C++” needs to be installed.

[image]

Install the oneAPI HPC toolkit (the base toolkit is not required). Only the fortran compiler is required (MPI is optional I think for this).
[image]

The Intel installer should pick up the visual studio installation. Ensure that your are running the verification from the "Intel oneAPI command prompt for Intel 64 for Visual Studio 2019".

The error of the subroutine not found is caused by an issue with case sensitivity (see comment by u\Ubuntz on [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/fea/comments/kppw72/help_with_abaqus_error_user_subroutine_is_missing/)).
Add the following line to the top of the FORTRAN source file (std_user.for  from the verify folder in this case).

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"disp"::DISP
```

For all other subroutines in actual use/development replace disp with the name of your subroutine, e.g., for a umat write

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"umat"::UMAT
```